# undefined method `responce' for #<Post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the models Post and Responce:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :category
    has_many :responces
end

class Responce < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :post
    default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }
end
```

I made feed by the example Ruby on Rails Tutorial

Michael Hartl

```
class ResponcesController < ApplicationController
  def feed
    Responce.where("post_id = ?", id)
  end

  def destroy
    @responce.destroy
    redirect_to post_path @post
  end
end
```

In the view _feed_item

```
  </span>
  <% if feed_item.user %>
  <%= link_to "delete", feed_item, method: :delete,
                                     data: { confirm: "You sure?" },
                                     title: feed_item.price %>
    <% end %>
</li>
```

When I click `<%= link_to "delete", feed_item, method: :delete,` rails gives an error: `undefined method 'responce' for #<Post`

```
def destroy
  @post.responce.destroy
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, it's not related, but more people would understand "response" instead of "responce"

Comment: Yes, it's spelled "response", not "responce".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your responce association is a has_many, so Post has the method "responces" not "responce".

Comment: O_o, and now rails gives undefined method `responce_path'

Comment: Thanks I'm added <%= link_to "delete", feed_item.post, method: :delete, and now its work but now, feed item dont be delete when I click...